# How to find the product distribution of two independent random variable with own distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

How to find the distribution function of $G$ given as $f_G(g)$, where $G = XY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variable with given pdf as

$f_X(x) = \frac{2x^{-\left(\frac{n +4}{n+2}\right)}}{(n + 2) r^2}$,  $x \in [\left(l^2 + r^2\right)^{-\frac{n +2}{2}}, l^{-(n+ 2)}]$ ,

Assuming  $x_{min} = \left(l^2 + r^2\right)^{-\frac{n +2}{2}}$ and   $x_{max}= l^{-(n+ 2)}$.

Furhter,
$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1 - y^2}}$ , $y \in [-1, 1]$.

Here $n, r, l$ are some parameter constant.

To find pdf of $G$ I have followed [Product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

As $-1 < y < 1$ and $\frac{z}{x_{max}} < y < \frac{z}{x_{min}}$. Also, $z \in \left[-x_{max}, x_{max}\right]$

Hence employing [Product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)

$f_G(g) = \int_{max\left\{-1,\frac{z}{x_{max}}\right\}}^{min\left\{1,\frac{z}{x_{min}}\right\}} f_Y(y)f_X(\frac{z}{y})\frac{1}{y}\,dy$.

Then after solving I found $f_G(g)$ as

$f_G(g) = \frac{2g^{-\left(\frac{n + 4}{n+2}\right)}\left[\beta\left\{\left(1 + \frac{r^2}{l^2}\right)^{(n +2)}, \frac{n+4}{n +2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}-\beta\left\{\frac{n+4}{n +2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right]}{\pi(n +2)r^2}$ with $g \in [-l^{-(n+2)}, l^{-(n +2)}]$.

However, problem is when integrating the pdf of $G$ over its range it is not coming as $1$. Can anyone please provide where I have gone wrong? I guess the limit in the integration of integrant $y$ is wrong can anyone please correct me.